# Is it possible to continue an export programatically via the Vault API?

Tags: google-vault-api

The following page explains Google Vault Exports with partial results [Partial Results](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2473458?hl=en#partial_results)

According to the documentation an export will be stopped after 24 hours.  The article explains that the export can be resumed through the UI.

Can this be accomplished through the Vault API?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Vault API documentation](https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/matters.exports)? Having a look at e.g. [exportOptions](https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/matters.exports#exportoptions) or [ExportStatus](https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/matters.exports#exportstatus) does not suggest that there is an option to do a partial export that can be resumed. However, it might be worth a clsoed look at the documentation.

Comment: Yeah Ive had a look. Added the question here in the hope that someone from the Google Vault team sees it and it prompts them to expose whatever functionality the UI uses publicly through the API

Comment: For this, you can file a feature request on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) - check first if a respective feature request already exists.